# Is the OS and browser used important when taking a screenshot?

Tags: user-research, user-expectation, user-centered-design

If I am taking a Screenshot (or say creating an animated gif) showcasing a particular aspect of a web-app (ie: dragging and dropping files from a folder onto the browser) is the OS/Browser combination I use to make the screenshot important?

I worry about alienating/confusing my users because:

- Windows XP may be more recognisable to more users, but at the same time could put off technically savvy users (by making my website seem antiquated) and Mac users also
- Windows Vista: Nope
- Windows 7: This seems like the safest course, are there any downsides to 7?
- Windows 8/8.1/10: Not overly widely used, may look unfamiliar
- Mac OS/Linux distros (Ubuntu etc): Similar to Windows 8, may be unfamiliar to many people

Then we get onto browsers. There's the worry that Internet Explorer may put off the tech savvy users, Chrome the privacy conscious, Firefox/Opera etc may look unfamiliar to many of my users.

I could of course do user-agent sniffing and show my screenshots/demo's with the browser/OS combination the user is using, but it's a lot of work!

What's the consensus here for OS/Browser choice when taking screenshots/recording GIF's and videos?

Comment: "is the OS/Browser combination I use to make the screenshot important?" = in the grand scheme of things, likely not. If it bothers you, use a different combo for each example.

Answer (score 4):

For the vast majority of screenshots, designers want users to focus on the browser **content**, not the browser itself.

So for most instances, I think it is better to use a nondescript browser rather than a specifically identifiable browser/OS combination.

There are a lot of nondescript browser frames out there...you can use an existing image or you can make your own (e.g. by taking a Safari or Chrome windows, desaturating and debadging it to your liking, and removing title bar buttons to help it frame the content more elegantly).

The advantages of the nondescript frame include:

- Prompts the user to anchor visual focus and memory on *your app* rather than the browser (i.e. they're more likely to remember your app no matter what browser they use).
- Helps avoid unnecessary technology biases and allergies (e.g. apple fanboy, android fanboy).
- More future-proof, since the less identifiable the browser window looks, the more resilient your screenshots are going to be to browser and OS updates later on.
- Allows you as a designer to adjust palette, borders, and all other browser details to optimize the presentation of your app content.
- Avoids potential trademark issues with Apple, Google and Microsoft (e.g. if you're developing a particularly edgy app like porn).

The only times I consider using specifically branded browsers are:

- For applications where there is a dominant user combination (e.g. for enterprise desktop software where Windows dominates; or for an iPhone app where safari dominates).
- For applications where the browser itself is significant (e.g. your product is a Chrome plugin).

Hope that helps

Comment: You could take a screenshot of the content within the browser and place on image similar to this - https://dribbble.com/shots/986009-Flat-Vector-Chrome-Frame